# Porque essa function não está funcionando?

Tags: javascript, funções, formulário

Sou leigo e estou aprendendo Javascript para um *app* simples híbrido. O primeiro empecilho é uma function que não está executando:

A dita cuja:

```
function calcular(){
    //ap1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ap1').value);
    var media, final;

    media = calculo.ap1.value.replace(",", ".");
    media = parseFloat(media);
    alert(media); 
}
```

Referenciei o arquivo onde ela se encontra no index e fiz a chamada em uma form:

```
<form action="javascript:calcular();" method="get"id="calculo" name="calculo" class="list">
```

Mesmo assim, não está rodando a function. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: E o que vem em `calculo.ap1.value`?

Comment: É o value de um imput dentro da form

Comment: Pode nos mostrar o valor dele? Coloque um `console.log(calculo.ap1.value)`.

Comment: Resolveu tirando a 'function' do 'action' e colocando no 'OnSubmit'  .. Valeu amigos!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de colocar sua função no action coloque no atributo específico para o evento javascript.

Fiz esse exemplo imaginando que os dados que serão chamados estejam corretos nas outras funções.

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="calcular()" method="get"id="calculo" name="calculo" class="list">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Js

```
function calcular()
{
       var valor, qtd,  media;

       valor = 10;
       qtd = 3;
       media = valor / qtd;
      console.log(media); 
}
```